# A Python-to-PHP compatible AES encryption with openssl_encrypt AES-CFB

Tags: php, python-3.x, encryption, interop, aes

I have simple PHP encryption code that I need to implement in Python3:

```
<?php

$iv = "your_secret_toke";
$token = "eW91cl9zZWNyZXRfdG9rZW45";
$key = "171d262039b68ccbdb2e72a17e4860ee";

$secret = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($token, 'AES-256-CFB', $key, 0, $iv));
echo $secret;
# SkZwbmljajRzSFVuaXdqLzROZEJleXpLZjNXVWNOWU8=

?>
```

I tried different solutions from SO with no luck:

```
import M2Crypto.EVP
from Crypto.Cipher import AES #I'm using pycryptodome
import base64

iv = b"your_secret_toke"
token = b"eW91cl9zZWNyZXRfdG9rZW45"
key = b"171d262039b68ccbdb2e72a17e4860ee"


cipher1 = M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher('aes_256_cfb', key, iv, 1)
cipher2 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)

encrypted1 = cipher1.update(token)# + cipher1.final()
encrypted2 = cipher2.encrypt(token)

secret1 = base64.b64encode(encrypted1)
secret2 = base64.b64encode(encrypted2)

print(secret1)
# JFpnicj4sHUniwj/4NdBeyzKf3WUcNYO
print(secret2);
# JFpnicj4sHUniwj/4NdBeyzKf3WUcNYO
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What's the problem?  Have you tried decrypting your cyphertext?  It just might be a difference in how the libraries handle streaming (in your python example) or fixed length encryption (your php example).

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to compare cyphertext to determine if encryption has occurred... There's a million things that can cause the cyphertext to be different, even if the cleartext is ultimately the same.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer good idea but my task is to implement password digest on a client side that will be compared on a server side :-(

Comment: @PaulProgrammer also I'm bet you're right about streaming, padding etc but I have same result with PHP, Java and JavaScript. Just need to understand what's wrong with my Python code

Comment: AES is a 2-way encryption technique. It is not suitable as a one-way hash.  I'd stick to SHA256 (or 384).  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function